# Show data from class in tooltip Blazor Syncfusion chart

Tags: c#, charts, blazor, syncfusion-chart

I retrieved the years and values from the database and successfully drew the graph. I managed to display the X and Y axis values in the tooltip. Now I want to display in the tooltip the percentage of what the user spent compared to last year. Did he spend more/less compared to last year and how much less.

Part of chart for tooltip:

```
<ChartTooltipSettings Enable="true" Fill="gray">
    <Template>
        @{
            var data = context as ChartTooltipInfo;
            <b>@data.X : @data.Y</b>
        }
    </Template>

</ChartTooltipSettings>
```

The percentage function works fine. The only problem is that I don't know how to display its value in the tooltip. So I want the format: "X value: Y value" and "You spent p% less/more than last year", less/more depends on it's value. If it's negative write less, if it's positive write more.

Part for calculating the percentage:

```
 public class YearsData
 {
     public int Year { get; set; }
     public decimal CostValue { get; set; }
     public decimal PercentageIncrease { get; set; }

     public void CalculatePercentageIncrease(decimal previousYearCost)
     {
         if (previousYearCost != 0)
         {
             PercentageIncrease = ((CostValue - previousYearCost) / previousYearCost) * 100;
         }
         else
         {
             PercentageIncrease = 0;
         }
     }
 }
```

```
CostYears = await CostService.GetCostsAsync() ?? new List<CostDTO>();
decimal previousYearCost = 0;  

foreach (var year in CostYears.Select(c => c.CreatedAt.Year).Distinct().OrderBy(year => year))
{
    var yearCost = await CostService.GetCostsByYearAsync(year);
    var costs = yearCost ?? new List<CostDTO>();
    var yearSum = costs.Sum(c => c.Value);
    var yearsData = new YearsData { Year = year, CostValue = yearSum };
    costByYears.Add(yearsData);

    yearsData.CalculatePercentageIncrease(previousYearCost);
    previousYearCost = yearSum;
}
```

I tried a lot of different things, but nothing works properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [TooltipRender](https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/chart/events#tooltiprender) event and manipulate the tooltip output with your class there.

Your event handler might be something like:

```
public void TooltipEvent(Syncfusion.Blazor.Charts.TooltipRenderEventArgs args)
{
    var series = args.Series as ChartSeries;

    if (series != null && series.Name == $"{MainSeriesName}")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(args.Data.PointIndex);
        var dataPoint = OriginalDataBoundToTheChart.ElementAtOrDefault(index);
        var value = MyClassValueMangler(args.Data.PointY) ?? args.Data.PointY.ToString();

        args.Text = $"{args.Data.PointX}<br /> <strong>{value}</strong>";
    }
}
```